# Is possible to generate Progress Bar with PIL in Python?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I want to generate progress/Hitpoints bar for my game in image using Python PIL. Here is one example from one current Discord bot (MewBot):

[image]

I mean something like in this image (I'm making RPG bot)

I already tried to make all percentages in different image templates, but I stopped this quickly, due this making take too much time, and results is not good.

EDIT:
Short version of this: I want to generate PNG file, where PIL paste HP bar, like is showed in image, but I don't know how to generate HP bar.

EDIT 2:
I'm showing images in Discord Embeds, and I upload images to Discord after generating.

Comment: You can easily create progress bar images in PIL, but getting them to display and update smoothly is the trick.

Comment: I generate image each time again when HP change. So only thing is generate this and display to existing image. @MarkRansom

Comment: What windowing system do you use?  That's going to be essential to getting an answer.

Comment: What windowing system? I want to generate PNG image @MarkRansom

Comment: So you're using a framework that opens PNG files and displays them? That's not evident from your question.  Nor is it obvious what is the problem you're having.

Comment: I added now these details to question @MarkRansom

Comment: Again, you're not including how you're displaying images.  If you're not yet, you need to pick a windowing package which is beyond the scope of a valid StackOverflow question.

Comment: @MarkRansom Added info about how I display image.

Comment: Are you using `pygame`? Or `sfml`? Or Qt?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm using PyGame in some places, but not much.